# Replacing variable values in defined string through awk / xargs

Tags: unix, awk, xargs

We are dynamically generating a string in bash to insert data in oracle database. The string is like

```
> echo $str1
insert into tbl select '$jobid','$1','$2','$3','$sdate' from dual ;
```

Here the variables $1,$2 ... are dynamic and can go upto 10

Now we have data in a file with same number of ':' separated datacolumns as there are numeric variables ( $1,$2.. ) in above string.

Challenge here is to have $1 replaced with 1st column of data, $2 with 2nd column and so on. This needs to be done for all rows of dataset and a separate file needs to be generated with "insert" string as base and with replaced data from the file.

For e.g the sample data

```
cat test.dat
ONLINE:odr1_redo_06a.log:NO
ONLINE:odr1_redo_06b.log:NO
ONLINE:odr1_redo_05a.log:NO

and the string is 
echo $str1
insert into tbl select '$jobid','$1','$2','$3','$sdate' from dual ;
```

Required output should be

```
insert into tbl select '$jobid','ONLINE','odr1_redo_06a.log','NO','$sdate' from dual ;
insert into tbl select '$jobid','ONLINE','odr1_redo_06b.log','NO','$sdate' from dual ;
insert into tbl select '$jobid','ONLINE','odr1_redo_05a.log','NO','$sdate' from dual ;
```

Tried using string as external variable in awk. No luck

```
cat test.dat | awk -F: -v var="$str1" '{print var}'
insert into tbl select '$jobid','$1','$2','$3','$sdate' from dual ;
insert into tbl select '$jobid','$1','$2','$3','$sdate' from dual ;
insert into tbl select '$jobid','$1','$2','$3','$sdate' from dual ;

or xargs
sed 's/:/ /g' test.dat | xargs -n3 bash -c "echo $str1"
insert into tbl select $jobid,$1,$2,$3,$sdate from dual
insert into tbl select $jobid,$1,$2,$3,$sdate from dual
insert into tbl select $jobid,$1,$2,$3,$sdate from dual
```

Writing a small loop and calling line by line bears overhead so don't prefer doing that. Any ideas how this can be done in optimal fashion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Awk, for each record, replace every literal $n with the value of nth field in your template by means of `gsub` function and print the result.

```
awk -F: -v tmpl="$str1" '{
  out = tmpl
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    gsub(("\\$" i), $i, out)
  print out
}' file
```

Proof of concept:

```
$ str1="insert into tbl select '\$jobid','\$1','\$2','\$3','\$sdate' from dual ;"
$
$ awk -F: -v tmpl="$str1" '{
>   out = tmpl
>   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
>     gsub(("\\$" i), $i, out)
>   print out
> }' file
insert into tbl select '$jobid','ONLINE','odr1_redo_06a.log','NO','$sdate' from dual ;
insert into tbl select '$jobid','ONLINE','odr1_redo_06b.log','NO','$sdate' from dual ;
insert into tbl select '$jobid','ONLINE','odr1_redo_05a.log','NO','$sdate' from dual ;
```